# How to generate a 0-1 sequence according to different probabilities efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to get a random 0-1 sequence. Now I generate the number one by one. My code is as follows:

```
p_arr = [0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8]
seq = []
for pb in p_arr:
  seq.append(np.random.choice(2, 1, p=[1-pb, pb]))
```

It's very time-consuming when the length of p_arr is very large (i.e. 10000). I wonder if there is another faster way to do this.

Comment: `seq = (np.random.rand(len(p_arr)) < p_arr).astype(int)`?

Comment: Thanks very much. It's a very brilliant method.

Comment: This looks like a binomial distribution: ```np.random.binomial(1, [0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8])```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Numpy, do:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNCoAgEIX3nmKWCiFFBG3qIhEhJBTkOI228PSmtXnfg/dDKR4e@5xPR54j4OMogQmAJGgzzDDB0uqugVYPVfoq4yqCvUskkTQb3L37IC@L8pspBTP8TpsQE9lafU6MoxLEhbI8qJxf)

```
import numpy as np
p_arr = [0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8]
seq = (np.random.rand(len(p_arr)) > p_arr).astype(np.uint8)
print(seq)
```

If you don't want to use Numpy then you can still make your code simpler:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwEETv@xVzTEBCShFE0B@RIilNMWA36zaXfn1sqpeZw5s3spVX5r7WtEjWAg085YXkGVRxw8O77gTvzi36FpeB1vhpaKA5K2REYhz7KwE7c0Ek8mQ6pPn/535lLO5NiO81wlsSTVzMrthavw)

```
import random
p_arr = [0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8]
seq = []
for pb in p_arr:
  seq.append(1 if random.random() > pb else 0)
print(seq)
```

Also notice that in both cases I thought that your `p_arr` contains probability of `0` (not `1`). If you want to inverse logic, then replace `>` with `<` in both of my codes.